# express.js not showing console.log message when routing

Tags: javascript, express

Note: I am very new to express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('id: ' + req.params.id + ' and name: ' + req.params.name);
});
var things = require('./things/things.js');

//both index.js and things.js should be in same directory
app.use('/things', things);
//Simple request time logger
app.use('/',function(req, res, next){
   console.log("A new request received at " + Date.now());

   //This function call is very important. It tells that more processing is
   //required for the current request and is in the next middleware
   //function/route handler.
   next();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I am learning about middleware functions and am trying to show a console.log message when I go to localhost:3000, but nothing shows up in my console, what am I missing here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that Express passes requests to both middleware and route handlers in order of their declaration. If any of them are able to handle the request (by sending back a response), any other matching middleware or route handlers that got declared later won't get called.

That's what's happening in your situation, where your middleware is declared *after* the route handlers.

Try moving your middleware to the front:

```
app.use('/',function(req, res, next){
   console.log("A new request received at " + Date.now());
   next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('id: ' + req.params.id + ' and name: ' + req.params.name);
});

var things = require('./things/things.js');

app.use('/things', things);
```

Answer (score 5):

First,  you need to check the file structure. If index.js and things.js are in the same directory then you need to change the require function to `var things = require('./things.js');`

Next, verify that you are looking in the correct place, the `console.log()` message will appear in the terminal window where you loaded the express server, not in the console in your web browser.

Comment: Ah, I had no idea it would show up in the terminal instead of browser console, why is that?

Comment: Express runs in node.js which runs on your server, not on the users browser. In your case, the server is just your computer but it still applies.

Answer (score 1):

> The console module provides a simple debugging console that is similar
> to the JavaScript console mechanism provided by web browsers. https://nodejs.org/api/console.html

Node Server generated console.log message in our terminal logs (Not on the browser).

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

[image]

Related: https://www.twilio.com/blog/guide-node-js-logging

Answer (score 0):

The correct 'id' and 'name' of the parameters in get is like this

```
app.get('/:id/:name', function(req, res) {
   res.send('id: ' + req.params.id + ' and name: ' + req.params.name);
});
```